# How to add strings to a 2d array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, tostring

So I have a 2d array of objects of class `Cell`. This is for a connect 4 game. Right now the size of this array is determined by an argument when the board is initiated. It looks like this:

```
public ConnectSome(int size){
    board = new Cell[(size*2)-1][(size+2)];
    for(int i = 0 ; i<board.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<board[i].length; i++)
            board[i][j] = new Cell();
```

I need to make a `toString()` method where it turns the board into a string and returns it. I already have a `toString()` method for the `Cell` class which returns the state of that cell (in this case its Yellow,Red or empty).

How do i make this method return a string not just showing each cell in a string form, but also surrounding it by a frame? I've had a go at it but I'm lost. It's supposed to look like this:

```
|.......|
|.......|
|.......|
|.......|
|.......|
|.......|
+-------+
```

Where the periods (.) are `Cell` objects that are "empty" (the result of using `toString()` on the `Cell`.) This is just an example board, the size can vary but the borders are what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: you could make use of the [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html#StringJoiner-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-). With this constructor you could make use of the delimeter parameter and the prefix parameter for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want 1 string with all the data or do you want a string for what is in each cell?

```
String s = null;
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++){
        String temp = board[i][j];
        s = s + temp;
    }
}
```

That should work

Comment: 1 String with all the data.

Comment: That definitely works, and you just gave me a good idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I got the problem correct then this should be the answer.

```
public String boardToString()
    {
    String str="";
        for(int i = 0 ; i<board.length; i++)
        {
        str+="|";
            for(int j = 0; j<board[i].length; i++)
            {
            Cell cell=board[i][j];
            str+=cell.toString();//assuming you have a toString method.
            }
        str+="|\n";
        }
       return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, the thing which you want to do is really straightforward and you can easily figure it out by yourself- you do not need any additional knowledge and special code than that what you have already shown.
Neverthless here you go (be aware, it's not working code- just an example):

```
//take your board and iterate over it
for(int i = 0 ; i<board.length; i++) {
    system.out.print("|"); //print left border of your game field
    for(int j = 0; j<board[i].length; i++) {
        system.out.print(board[i][j].toString()); // print cell state
    }
    system.out.println("|"); //print right border
}
```

edit: my bad -> if you want to get all this data into one string instead of printing then replace system.out.print with strings joining as in other posts.